# Taking recurring payments via Node.js in the UK

Tags: node.js, payment

I'm currently developing a small SAAS project which is subscription based. Obviously, if I could, I'd use Stripe but being in the UK my choices are limited.

So my question is, what is a good way of taking recurring payments using Node.js in the UK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Stripe UK Beta Now Available

A Stripe UK beta account was made available to me as I had previously expressed an interest for UK payments through their global webpage.

> We're getting in touch because you asked to be notified when Stripe
>   was available in the United Kingdom. Good news: we are up and running
>   in private beta....

To register an interest:

https://stripe.com/global

Taking from today:

- Visa
- MasterCard

Payments:

- pounds
- U.S. dollars

Soon:

- American Express
- Euro-denominated

Rich

Comment: Thanks, I've actually been signed up to the Stripe UK beta now for some time :) I'll mark this as the answer, since Stripe provides a **much** better service.

Answer (score 1):

I find modules that works only with PayPal and the most popular is [paypal-ec](https://npmjs.org/package/paypal-ec) that comes with simply example @ GitHub. Other seven npm PayPal [modules](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/paypal)

Comment: paypal-ec only covers the express checkout API.  He's asking about recurring payments, which uses a different API.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely check out [Paymill](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/). It's basically stripe but in European countries, huge following already and it's a super easy to use service. They may have a node module to help you with it, if not they have super easy APIs which you can use to setup things like recurring payments.

I would completely avoid PayPal these days. Waste of time.

**Edit**

Just had a check for you. There are a few npm modules knocking around, have a look at https://github.com/komola/paymill-node